# can connect to mlab but unable to import the document

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am connecting to mlab using the mongo import command to import the json collection.

Now i am able to connect to mlab. However, it does not import the document.

```
imported 0 documents
```

I have created the input file (test.json) in C:/data/db folder.

The foll is an illustration of the command:
[image]

I'd appreciate any guidance on where i am going wrong with this.

Comment: Well screenshots are not going to help anyone here. What is in `test.json`? It needs to be valid for import or it will do nothing. You should be posting the "text" of that. And it should be "minimal" as in 2 documents or so. And you should actually be trying to import that before even posting here, since that will likely show you your problem.

Comment: so neil, i'm sure doing sthg v wrong. i created a test.json file as an input file. it is an empty file. i created it so that my posts from mlab could feed into the test.json file.

Comment: Include the content "small" file in your question. The issue is that `mongoimport` does not recognize that there is anything to import by its own structural rules. Outside of that, a good place for you to start is to do a `mongoexport` on a collection with documents already in it, then look at that to compare with the format of what you are trying to import. That should tell you something.

Comment: so i already have a collection in mlab that i wish to import to my machine. the collection on mlab is called 'posts' and i am just trying to import that. i'm not sure what you mean by 'The issue is that mongoimport does not recognize that there is anything to import by its own structural rules.'

Comment: the foll is the structure of my document in mlab: `{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59227c3e734d1d5883729c91"
    },
    "title": "XXX",
    "url": "https://google.com",
    "description": "XXX"
}` how do i need to format my input file (test.json) so that the collection from mlab is imported.

Comment: It sounds like there may be confusion as to what the `mongoimport` client does: it reads the input file (specified by `--file`) and imports it into the specified database (your mLab database in this case). If you're trying to move data from your mLab database to localhost, you need to use `mongoexport` to export the data locally, then use `mongoimport` to import the data into your local database from the file created by `mongoexport`.

Comment: @pneumee ah... OK... so i need to view export and import from the point of view of mlab. mongoexport is pushing data from mlab to the local machine. and mongoimport is pulling data from the localmachine to mlab. i tried and it works now. thanks pneumee for the clarification.

Comment: @Nosail - great! Some additional clarification: mongoexport is for migrating data from a MongoDB database to text file(s) as JSON (by default). mongoimport is for migrating data from text files to a MongoDB database.

Comment: @pneumee - noted. thanks v much.